# NodeJS Joi Vlidation - How to return JSON response instead of a string?

Tags: json, node.js, validation, response, joi

Recently, Iv'e been using the [Joi validation library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) in-order to validate the data which comes in from a request (building a RESTful API).
I was using the .label() method to generate a string response and send it back to the user, but I couldn't find any way to send a JSON response back to the user?
Tried sending a premade JSON inside the string, searching the documentation and the internet of course - couldn't find any mention of it.
Current code example:

```
textField: Joi.string().required().max(4).label("This example field didn't pass the testing phase, please try again)"),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data in case of error,try `.error()` method. you can pass error in it.

Comment: Hi mehta-roha,
This is what I get: `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Must provide a valid Error object or a function.`
How can I send JSON with it?

Comment: use `error.message`, you will get the custom error message.

Comment: Doesn't work as you need to specify each function value to it's own.
Any code example?

Comment: `textField: Joi.string().required().max(4).error('{"testJSON":"This example field didn't pass the testing phase, please try again"}')`